# Regex to find words with letters at start and end usign variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find words that begin with a certain letter, and end with another, using variables and regex. This is the expression and input I am using, am I going wrong anywhere?

```
start = str(input("What should it start with?"))
end = str(input("What should it end with?"))
words = re.findall(r"\b"+ start +"\w*?"+ end +"\b", dictionary)
```

Dictionary is a file I open containing some words.

Comment: Did you run it? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: @Toto I got null, just an empty string

Comment: Maybe a good usecase for f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `r` for the other string patterns:

```py
words = re.findall(r"\b" + start + r"\w*?" + end + r"\b", dictionary)
```